# ExecuteNonQuery C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The parameterized query '(@username
>   nvarchar(3),@password nvarchar

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] 
(
    [Username]  VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [Pasword]   VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [FName]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [LName]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Location]  VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Profesion] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [email]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [gender]    VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [money]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [property]  VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);
```

And this is the C# code:

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] Values (@username,@password,@name,@lastname,@location,@profesion,@email,@gender,@money,@pro);", c);
    NewUser.Connection = c;

    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtFName.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLName.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", txtprofession.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rbgendere.SelectedItem.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", null);

    Session["CurentUserid"] = txtuser.Text;

    c.Open();
    NewUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    c.Close();

    Session["Conect"] = (bool)true;
    Response.Redirect("Finish Had Member.aspx", true);
}
```

Please help

Comment: That error message looks truncated to me. Please post the *complete* error message.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The parameterized query '(@username nvarchar(3),@password nvarchar(6),@name nvarchar(3),@' expects the parameter '@pro', which was not supplied.

Comment: Please edit the question to include that then.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a value of `DBNull.Value` instead of just `null` for `@pro`?

Comment: its all of it (from the vs not from web)

Comment: it must be null at the beginig

Comment: Yes, and that's what `DBNull.Value` means.

Comment: Just remark, You can remove this line `NewUser.Connection = c;` besause you are passing connection object in create `SqlCommand` Object

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're specifying `null` as the value for `@pro`. From the docs for [`AddWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Use `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`, to indicate a null value.

However, I would also suggest avoiding using `AddWithValue` to start with - call `Add` and specify the parameter type, then set the `Value` property. For example:

```
NewUser.Parameters.Add("@money", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
```

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for detailed reasoning behind doing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate you are genius